# How to type from the source directory on mac

Tags: source

In the website http://gfs.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Mac_OSX_Installation

```
In this line:

type from the source directory ...
```

What is `source directory` referring to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be the directory with the contents of your tarball. Most likely the tarball itself will contain a single top level directory, with everything inside that. This is the one you are looking for! Since the next command is to run an `autogen.sh` script, you can check by confirming that the directory has one of those :)